# File not found error, after %run magic command. In specific cell from other jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

My issue is the following, i am currently using a %run magic method. Inside a jupyter notebook(x). That is basically running another notebook of mine(y), but the thing is when i reach the y notebook read_csv() line. It gives me an error, file not found.  To make it clearer, here is step by step.

1- I run this specific cell inside notebook x

[image]

2- The cell manages to find my y notebook and runs it

3- But when i get to this cell from the y notebook

[image]

4 - The %run cell gives me this error

[image]

I can guarantee, that the cell works when i run the y notebook individually. Would appreciate some explanation on the why is this error ocurring?